# Is there a way to make columns into rows under a multi-index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have a dataframe:

```
data = {
 'name': ['IBM', 'MSFT', 'AAPL'],
 'Revenue': [111, 222, 333],
 'NetIncome': [41, 28, 33,],
 'date': [20100331,20100331,20100331]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('name')
```

[image: Output]

How can I make revenue and Net Income become rows under each name, with date as the only column?
For example:

```
                   date
name             20100331
IBM   Revenue      111
      NetIncome     41
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.set_index('date', append=True).unstack().stack(0)
```

Output:

```
date            20100331
name                    
AAPL Revenue         333
     NetIncome        33
IBM  Revenue         111
     NetIncome        41
MSFT Revenue         222
     NetIncome        28
```

Comment: name is in the same column as Rev and NetInc when I try this

Comment: Can you run your trial with the dataframe given in this question?  Does it work?